# Change iOS 7 morenavigationcontroller text colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've managed to change the "more" title and font/color with the following code into appdelegate.m:

```
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.titleView = label;
label.text = self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title;
[label release];
```

however as soon as I go into one of the tabs form the more tableview the title changes back to bold, black text and the back button is blue text.

Any ideas how to change those labels? I've tried:

```
    self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"test 1";
    self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.backItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"test 2";
```

But neither affect the back button title so I'm guessing that's not the correct item.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way to change back button title

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnBack = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                        initWithTitle:@"test 1"
                        style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                        target:self
                        action:nil];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.backBarButtonItem=btnBack;
```

Comment: This worked, it's accessing the same object as my "test 1" above, can you tell me why I wasn't able to simply alter the title?

Comment: "When this navigation item is immediately below the top item in the stack, the navigation controller derives the back button for the navigation bar from this navigation item. [...] If you want to specify a custom image or title for the back button, you can assign a custom bar button item (with your custom title or image) to this property instead."